# Bootstrap Carousel Picture Thumbnails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I used jsfiddle to get a solution for this from this link as I was trying to find out how to have picture thumbnails in a carousel: http://jsfiddle.net/8rv96jex/2/

Everything works except I cannot click on the picture thumbnails. I've checked the code probably a dozen times to make sure there's nothing small missing but no luck.  I'll copy code below.  I'm new to RoR and Web Dev. so appreciate any thoughts on possible solutions.

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/css-toggle-switch/latest/toggle-switch.css" />
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="segment.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/checkout/button.css"></link>

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="500">
...

<script src="segment.js"></script>
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
```

javascript/application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.collapse').collapse;

var $root = $('html, body');
    $('.navbar-nav a').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top-50
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
            });

$(".segment-select").Segment();

var options = {
    agreed: [
        {price: 19, link: 'link1'},
        {price: 199, link: 'link2'},
        {price: 449, link: 'link3'}
    ],
    nope: [
        {price: 39, link: 'link4'},
        {price: 249, link: 'link5'},
        {price: 499, link: 'link6'}
    ]
};

function fillContent(interval) {
    var data = options[interval];

 $('.content').each(function(index) {
        var content = $(this);

        content.hide();

        content.find('.price').text('$' + data[index].price);
        content.find('.link').attr('href', data[index].link);

        content.fadeIn("3000");
    });

 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
 interval: 4000
 });

 // handles the carousel thumbnails
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
 var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
 var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
 id = parseInt(id, radix);
 $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
 });

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
id = parseInt(id, radix);
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
$('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
});

}

});
```

Comment: what does this line of code do?? `$('#myCarousel').carousel(id);`

Comment: `Everything works except I cannot click on the picture thumbnails` I can see your fiddle working fine, I was able to click on the thumbnails

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my install of JS and/or Jquery.  Possibly the wrong order in my `<head>` tag.  Any clues possibly from there?

Comment: Sorry if that's a rookie question.  This is driving me insane for a couple days now and I'm pretty new to Rails.  Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: the head tag looks ok, nothing wrong there.

Comment: Here's what I get when I copy my code back into JSfiddle.  (https://jsfiddle.net/L9c90v5j/)   Anything I might be missing here?

Comment: Sorry @Reddy trying to understand. - `.selected img {
 opacity:0.5;
}`   That's all there is in CSS no?  And I added the resource as well.  What am I missing?

Comment: Thats the css which you have written. But the plugin css will be there right?  just like the plugin .js, you need to add that css